# Summing power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

Lets have series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n$$
Obviously, its convergence radius is 1. I should sum it, but don't know what's up with the double factorial. There is a hint in the textbook that I should multiply its derivative by (1-x). But don't really know how it could help.

Comment: There are *lots* of ways something like that *could* help -- you won't know if any of them happen unless you actually try it out and see what you can do with the result

Comment: But the main problem is, that I have no idea how to work with the double factorial.

Comment: I don't believe that at all. I bet you could, for example, simplify $(2n-1)!! \cdot (2n+1)$. Or maybe even $\frac{n}{(2n)!!}$ too!

Comment: Believe what you want, you are free. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334359/determine-convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n-1)!}{4^n n!^2}x^n \color{blue}{=} \sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{-1/2}{n}(-1)^n x^n = \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1}.$$

Details of $\color{blue}{=}$:
$$\binom{-1/2}{n}(-1)^n = \frac{(-1/2)(-3/2)\cdots(-(2n-1)/2)}{n!}(-1)^n = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}.$$

As an alternative way, you may just play a bit with the [generating function of Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to rewrite the double factorial? Thank you.

Comment: @user74200: done.