# The sum function of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a power series as shown below
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}$$
How to get its sum function?
Any help will be appreciated.

Now I have come up with a solution: assume 
$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}.
$$
Then
$$
S'(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}x^{2n}=1+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}x^{2n-1}.
$$
Now put
$$
Q(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}x^{2n-1}$$
Integrating both side of the equation, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\int Q(x)dx&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-2)!!}{(2n-1)!!}x^{2n}\\
&=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-2)!!}{(2n-1)!!}x^{2n-1}\\
&=xS(x)
\end{split}
$$
Therefore we have 
$$
\begin{split}
Q(x)&=[xS(x)]'=S(x)+xS'(x)\\
&\qquad\qquad\Updownarrow\\
S'(x)&=1+x\big(S(x)+xS'(x)\big)
\end{split}
$$
i.e.
$$S'(x)+\frac{x}{x^2-1}S(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
Then, by solving this differential equation I get
$$
S(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
Are there other ways to obtain this sum?

Comment: It's a well-known function! What do you know so far about power series?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip My series is very weak, I only know the power series expansion of common functions and the common series summation method. I know very little about the series with double factorial type, so what is this well-known function?

Comment: Does this similar question and answer help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825693/summing-power-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-12nxn?rq= ?

Comment: @JoshuaZ   I will go check it out, thank you